How to use google_application_credentials with vercel?
I have deployed a express server in vercel. But I need to set the google_application_credentials in the app to get access to my Google service account.
I have tried to set the credentials in the environment variable but did not work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Do not use google_application_credentials. That is a variable set by the Google Cloud Tools. 2) You probably want to set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the full path to the service account JSON file. 3) Edit your post and show what you tried and the code that requires Google Cloud credentials (service account).

